# Add user group to another user group with wix v3

Tags: wix, windows-installer, scheduled-tasks, wix3

I need to add group within a group
e.g. COMPUTER\Users group to the "Backup Operators" group.

Wix provides a way to add a user to a group using the GroupRef Element but does not seem to provide an obvious way to add a group

Can this be done? If so how?

Comment: I don't think it is possible for local groups to be members of other local groups.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681621(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd need to write a CustomAction. It probably wouldn't take too much to extend the existing User and Group CustomAction in the WiX toolset to support this. In fact, there is a feature request open for this behavior in the WiX toolset today. Maybe you could contribute the fix?

Comment: Being new to WIX I am not sure if I can do this but I will give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

Some resources:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370283(VS.85).aspx (Local Group Functions)
<del>http://support.microsoft.com/kb/119671</del> (link seems to be broken, leaving in for now)

I got some C++ code that wraps user and group creation, and as I recall adding groups to groups should be possible with relative ease. Unfortunately I no longer have access to that code-base, perhaps the Boost library has support, or a simple VBScript should suffice.

I don't like to make software recommendations, but I have found that the [**VbsEdit application**](http://www.vbsedit.com) features a large library of standard VBScript samples - perhaps you can find a ready made script in its' sample library.